# Floodlight controller routing algorithme

Tags: sdn

I recently started working with SDN and floodlight controller. I want to changing routing algorithme in floodlight by deleting the algorithm exist (Dijkstra algorithm), any link for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floodlight controller has a topology manager that takes care of maintaining the
network graph, functionalities for finding routes through the topology via algorithm for the controller. Dijakstra runs in topology manager. You may need to update the Topology manager and its related dependencies as per your requirement.

The below link could be one good starting point 
https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/blob/master/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/topology/TopologyManager.java

Based on Dijskstra, the Yen's algorithm shall form shortest path, in the order of shortest path which shall get stored in pathCache for usage. The Topology manager interacts and helps in exposing the path information.

Application modules like Forwarding module shall retrieve the path from Topology Manager and then insert flows over the path based on learned source, destination.

Controller module like TopologyService help in maintaining the topology related information for the controller, as well as to find routing in the network.

You may need to update the modules as per your algorithm with few additional details https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/floodlightcontroller/pages/1343513/How+to+Write+a+Module

Comment: Thank you for this explanation